# Scrollbar Flickering When Resizing Window

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scrollbar

I am working on a table created in react, and implementing a horizonal scrollbar. When I have overflow set to `overflow-x: scroll`, and `overflow-y: hidden` to hide the vertical scroll bar, the scrollbar "works" okay, although for some reason, when I am resizing my window to make it **smaller**, the scrollbar flickers on then off when it isnt even needed, even when sizing down by one pixel, it does a quick scrollbar flash, then goes away.

I am thinking that it is a re-rendering issue perhaps, although I am unsure and I don't know what else to try (I feel like I have tried a million different things.

All help appreciated!